# How to transform firedac tquery results to tstringlist

Tags: delphi, firedac

There is a query:

```
SELECT id FROM level;
```

How can i get TQuery results (multiple ids' strings) and transform to TStringList?

Comment: You can `FetchAll` tuples and without moving cursor iterate or dump internal `Table` storage.

Comment: Why not just iterate through your dataset and add the required field to the StringList

Comment: @Fero, that can be slower because of cursor movement (depends on used cursor).

Comment: @Victoria the OP did not specify if he wants the fastest way to achieve the desired results, the resultset could be not huge.

Comment: FetchAll and then what operate?

Answer (score 4):

When you have all tuples fetched on client, you can access the internal storage this way (there's no enumerator implemented for the internal storage collections at this time, so this is the minimum you need to write when using it):

```
var
  Row: Integer;
begin
  for Row := 0 to FDQuery.Table.Rows.Count - 1 do 
    StringList.Add(FDQuery.Table.Rows[Row].GetData(0)); { ← 0 here is the column index }
end;
```

If you need to operate with column names, you can use another **GetData** method overload:

```
var
  Row: Integer;
begin
  for Row := 0 to FDQuery.Table.Rows.Count - 1 do 
    StringList.Add(FDQuery.Table.Rows[Row].GetData('ID')); { ← ID here is the column name }
end;
```

Or ask and remember the column index only once:

```
var
  Col, Row: Integer;
begin
  Col := FDQuery.Table.Columns.ColumnByName('ID').Index; { ← get column index by name }
  for Row := 0 to FDQuery.Table.Rows.Count - 1 do 
    StringList.Add(FDQuery.Table.Rows[Row].GetData(Col));
end;
```

The **GetData** storage access has an advantage of not moving dataset cursor, and in the end it's the same way used by FireDAC for fetching data when using **As<T>** accessors (the returned **Variant** is just implicitly casted in this case).

Comment: This is an advanced techinique.

Comment: @Fero, FireDAC can do far much more than is currently documented. For example just that `Table` storage (`TFDDatSTable` class) is very flexible (it's an extended .NET `DataTable` class).

Comment: @Victoria I like the comment in the code, it's helpful too :)

Answer (score 2):

```
yourStringList.Clear;
yourQuery.First;
while not yourQuery.Eof do
begin
 yourStringList.Add(yourQuery.FieldByName('id').AsString);
 yourQuery.Next;
end;
```